# Neo4j parent-child relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a node and I need to find all parent relationship to it till root.

So, if I have:
A->B->C->D(root)
A->E->F->D(root)

A is the node I have and I need all the ancestors of it.

I tried the cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:yo {name:"foo"})-[:HELLO*1..]->(p:yo) RETURN p
```

But it shows me a list like this: B,C,D,E,F. So the connection between them is lost. Is it possible to have list like [[B->C->D],[E->F->D]]

I saw this query on a website and it works. But it returns [[A,B],[A,B,C],[A,B,C,D]]. I don't need the subpaths.

```
start c = node:node_auto_index ( object_id = ‘10179’  )
MATCH path =  c <- [ : PARENT_OF* ] – p
return  distinct
length ( path )  AS PATH_LENGTH
, extract ( n in nodes ( path ) : n.object_id ) as the_path
order by length ( path )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for something like this.  Match paths that start at the **A** node and end with a node that is not a `:CHILD_OF` another node. This will return two rows of node collections per your sample data:

```
MATCH p=(a:Node {name: 'A'})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(end:Node)
WHERE NOT (end)-[:CHILD_OF]->()
RETURN tail(nodes(p))
```

You could also `collect()` the result if you wanted a single row returned.

```
MATCH p=(a:Node {name: 'A'})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(end:Node)
WHERE NOT (end)-[:CHILD_OF]->()
RETURN collect(tail(nodes(p)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Dave :D

Comment: One more thing: What if I want node a in the collection too?

Comment: simply remove the `tail()` function from the return statement and you will receive the full list of nodes in the path.

Comment: Is it possible to filter it more? As in, if I want the path to end before the point it hits a certain label. Like : match p=(a:Node {name: 'A'})-[:CHILD_OF*]->(end:Node)
where not (end:yoyo)-[:CHILD_OF]->()
return tail(nodes(p))